# How to use "INSERT OR IGNORE" with "UPDATE" in Room database?

Tags: android-sqlite, android-room

How can I make this query in Room database ?

```
@Query("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ChapterInfo (chapterId, readDate) VALUES (:chapterId, :readDate) UPDATE ChapterInfo SET readDate = :readDate WHERE chapterId = :chapterId")
void insertReadChapterDate(long chapterId, Date readDate);
```

When I try do it I got error: "There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "UPDATE": syntax error)" ?

Do you have any idea how I can insert value to table but if record with this id exists - to update it?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe usual way of Insert in Room will do?

In your Dao:

`@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insert(ChapterInfo chapterInfo)`

Invoking your DAO-method your put object (new|modified) as a parameter. If its primary key|keys is already in DB, Room founds row in the table and replaces row's fields. Otherwise Room adds new row.

**Updated**

Your initial variant can be fixed as well (if chapterId - is a Primary Key):

```
@Query("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ChapterInfo ('chapterId', 'readDate') VALUES (:chapterId, :readDate)
void insertReadChapterDate(long chapterId, Date readDate);
```

**Updated (13/05/2020)**

*It became clear that question was about:
How to set some values in DB including scenarios:*

1. *There is no row with such Primary Key. Then function should add new row, set given values and rest of columns in the row should be not-initialised*.
2. *There is row with such Primary Key.Then function should update only given values and the rest of columns - leave without change*.

As a decision to that, you could implement set of two SQL-commands "INSERT OR IGNORE" and "UPDATE" inside one transaction:

```
@Query("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ChapterInfo (chapterId, readDate) VALUES (:chapterId, :readDate) 
void insertOrIgnoreChapterDate(long chapterId, Date readDate);

@Query("UPDATE ChapterInfo SET readDate = :readDate WHERE chapterId = :chapterId)"
void updateChapterDate(long chapterId, Date readDate);

@Transaction
void insertUpdateChapterDate(long chapterId, Date readDate){
    insertOrIgnoreChapterDate(long chapterId, Date readDate);
    updateChapterDate(long chapterId, Date readDate);
}
```

So from outside you should use only "insertUpdateChapterDate" method

Comment: It is not good solution because, I can have more values in raw

Comment: Can you explain your thought?

Comment: Table ChapterInfo [chapterId, readDate, otherData], I want update raw in this table: "UPDATE ChapterInfo SET readDate = :readDate WHERE chapterId = :chapterId" but  when nnot existe raw with this chapterId, I want to insert new raw with chapterId and readDate

Comment: Ok, I suppose I begin to understand you. You want to tell that when you want to invoke your method "insertReadChapterDate" you have only "chapterId" and "readDate", and you don't have "otherData" on some purpose. That's why you want to prevent scenario, when if there is row with that "chapterId", field "otherData" will be overriden and you'll loose it. That's it?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want